# Expo to react native init

Tags: android, react-native, expo

To this point, I developed my app with Expo. I don't want to use expo anymore, and his way of building a standalone app with (exp build:android), it takes a long time to build and generating apk file, plus APK on phone and especially data stored in a phone is large. I have around 12k lines of code...

How can I convert expo project to react native init as fast as possible? I want to build my app on my own, via android studio. In my app, I only use expo for "linear gradient" and nothing else...

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can eject expo project using `expo eject` (which will create `ios` and `android` directories in your project folder).

[Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject)